# Spring cron job working in local but not in amazon instance

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, scheduling

I have developed a spring boot project. 
It uses `@EnableScheduling` and `@Scheduled` annotations to schedule task. I have tried both ways to schedule my function.

1)

```
@Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${scheduler.initialDelay}", fixedDelayString = "${scheduler.fixedDelay}")
```

2)

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * *")
```

In both ways when I run my code locally, It gets run perfectly fine. But when I deploy my code to AWS instance using auto scaling group, spring application gets start, but after that nothing is happening. I don't even see any logs or error about scheduler. Application is running but scheduler is not getting invoked. 
It seems very strange to me. And since its working perfectly very well in local, it is difficult to debug also.

Comment: Can you post the code that's failing?

Comment: try to create a scheduling hard coded for example ` @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000) public void printSomethingToConsole() {}` and deploy it to aws and see what happens

Comment: I suspect that it is running in AWS just that it is throwing an exception that you are not expecting.  I'd add more logging of your task and maybe wrap it in a try/cache to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Problem got resolved. I changed instance AMI type and its working perfectly fine. Strange, as earlier also, AMI was compatible with spring boot. But by changing AMI, its working fine.

Comment: check the timezone.

Comment: @user3462649 What AMI did you use to solve this issue ? Would be great if you put your solution as an answer so that it can help fellow developers facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I believe its to do with the Springboot default threadpool for scheduling. It worked for me when i altered the below setting in application.properties / yaml

> spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=20